# Syntax error in my query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here i have a text area where i am going to put a value similar to this:

> Sylhet,Sylhet,Sylhet,Khadim Nagar
>
> Sylhet,Sylhet,Sylhet,Mogla Bazar
>
> Sylhet,Sylhet,Sylhet,Mullar Gaon

each comma seperated string contains four value for four different field in database

in my database there are four field

```
bangladesh_info (Division,District,Thana,Union)
```

i want to capture the value from my text area and add three rows in their respective field .I wrote the following code where i used php pdo to connect and execute an insert command .I am getting

```
"new records created successfully"
```

but no value is getting inserted in the database .What might go wrong here? i am not getting any error !

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['text'])){

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myown";
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$servername};dbname={$dbname}", $username, $password);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO bangladesh_info (Division,District,Thana,Union)
    VALUES (:division, :district, :thana,:union)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':division', $division);
    $stmt->bindParam(':district', $district);
    $stmt->bindParam(':thana', $thana);
    $stmt->bindParam(':union',$union);
    $myarr=explode("\n",$_POST['text']);
    foreach($myarr as $each){

         list($div,$dis,$tha,$uni)=explode(',',$each);
         echo $uni.'</br>';

         $division=$div;
         $district=$dis;
         $thana=$tha;
         $union=$uni;
         $stmt->execute();

    }
    echo "New records created successfully";

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

?>

<html>
<body>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ; ?>' method='POST' >
     <textarea name='text' id='mytextarea'></textarea>
     <input type='submit' value='submit' >
</form>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Union` is [**reserved keyword**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql it must be in backtick OR change your column name to some other which is not in the list of reserved keyword

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO bangladesh_info (`Division`,`Distric`,`Thana`,`Union`)
    VALUES (:division, :district, :thana,:union)");
```

Comment: wow...thanks a lot :D

Comment: how i can see this  type of errors ?

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518354/php-mysql-pdo-prepared-insert-does-not-work-and-no-error-messages